# how to use file to re copy a string using position and words only

Tags: recreate

use a file to create the sentence

```
sentence = 'the cat sat on the cat mat'

indivdual_words = ['the', 'cat', 'sat', 'on', 'mat']
positions = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5]

f = open('word_file.txt', 'w+')
f.write(str(words))
f.close()

f = open('pos_file.txt', 'w+')
f.write(str(positions))
f.close()
```

program should see 1 as the and 2 as cat etc

Comment: `user's sentence = ` is an invalid parameter name

Comment: @shash678 I mean, he did....

Comment: Ah, good old OCR GCSE Computing.  Best of luck with your assessed coursework.  In general, people on SO want to see some sort of attempt made to solve the problem yourself first.  Downvoted.

Comment: Please stop completely rewriting your question. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're storing everything as strings, you'll end up with file contents that match a valid python expression. You can use `ast.literal_eval` to get the actual python object out of the string representation.

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open('word_file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().strip()
    words = ast.literal_eval(data)

with open('pos_file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().strip()
    pos = ast.literal_eval(data)
```

Then just do the opposite of what you did before.

```
result = " ".join([words[i-1] for i in pos])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dumping the representation of the lists, the best way is to read them back using `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast

with open('word_file.txt') as f:
    indivdual_words = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
with open('pos_file.txt') as f:
    positions = ast.literal_eval(f.read())
```

then recreate the sentence using a list comprehension to generate the words in sequence, joined with spaces:

```
sentence = " ".join([indivdual_words[i-1] for i in positions])
```

result:

```
the cat sat on the cat mat
```

Answer (score 0):

After you create the reading and writing capable file objects (w for word file, n for index file):

1) iterate through the word file object, appending each word to an empty list

2) iterate through the index file object, assigning each word in word list to temporary variable word via index from index file object, and then add that word to the originally empty sentence you are trying to form.

```
word_list = []
for word in w:
wordlist.append(word)

sentence = ''
for index in n:
word = wordlist[index]
sentence+= word
sentence+= ' '
```